# Comparison inside of a function that takes series as arguments

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, series

Lets say I have a simple function like this:

```
def func(a,b):
    if a>b:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

what I want to happen is when I feed lists like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and [-1, 3, -3, 5, -5] to it that it would return a list [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]. That doesnt't happen, it says "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous..." and that's understandable, inside of the function is compares whole lists, spits out a list of boolean values and that cannot be interpreted by if. Is there an elegant way of doing it without a loop?

Comment: You aren't working with lists, but with `pandas.Series` objets. This function doesn't really need to exist, all you need is `a > b`.... pandas series already support vectorized operations

Comment: I know that this function doesn't need to exist, I am trying to write a much more complicated function, I used this example for simplicity

Comment: OK, then again, all you need is `a > b` Have you tried it?